# Line-scan camera calibration

Tags: camera-calibration

I read some paper about line-scan camera calibration. It seems that it all need to acquire pattern images from different posture to solve the intrinsic and extrinsic matrix. However, limited to the mechanical structure, I can barely acquire images like this.
I wonder if there is a line-scan calibration algorithm need not images of pattern in different posture? Or it just doesn't work mathematically?

The only image(chessboard) plane i can acquire is parallel to optical axis of camera.

Here is some of paper I read:

1. Gupta, Rajiv, and Richard I. Hartley. "Linear pushbroom cameras." IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence 19.9 (1997): 963-975.
2. Zhang, Zhengyou. "A flexible new technique for camera calibration." IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence 22.11 (2000): 1330-1334.
3. Draréni, Jamil, Sébastien Roy, and Peter Sturm. "Plane-based calibration for linear cameras." International Journal of Computer Vision 91 (2011): 146-156.

Comment: what _can_ you physically do for calibration? _show_ your situation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your tips! The only image(chessboard) plane i can acquire is parallel to optical axis of camera.